# Javascript how to extract time from the format like 5:00 am/pm

Tags: javascript, time

I have a value of 12:00am in a javascript variable.

I want to to pass the time 12:00 only to database.

Please suggest me how to extract time only by excluding am/pm using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your time string in a variable, say `timeStr`. You can strip off all non-sumerics and `:` using the following:

```
timeStr = timeStr.replace(/[^\d:]+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just only want to remove last two chars, you can try this way:

```
("12:00am").slice(0, -2); // "12:00"
```